# Why can't my switch statement move to the next case?

Tags: c++, integer, switch-statement

```
int main()
{
    int cstats, choice;
    int rhp, hp, i, init, atk, def, matk, mdef, dmg, mdmg, agi, magi;
    cout << "Please choose your specialty: ";
    cout << "[1] Offense [2] Magic [3] Defense [4] Speed";
    switch(cstats)
    case 1:
        atk = 15;
        def = 5;
        agi = 5;
        break;
}
```

This is my line at the beginning. As you see on the code. I want to have a different integers using switch statement but when I always putting break; and move on to the next case I always encounter a problem. Is it possible to have a choices on integers using switch? Or am I just doing it wrong? I'm making a Text-Based Game.

Comment: In addition to answer below, you also need to get the value for `cstats` from the user.

Comment: I already added that part. I forgot it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off -- you need to enclose the `switch` block in curly braces:

```
switch(cstats)
{
    case 1:
        atk = 15;
        def = 5;
        agi = 5;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the missing curly braces in the switch statement. `cstats` is undefined and reading it before defining it in some way is undefined behaviour.

Read about how to get an integer from the command line here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

As an aside, you should Always define your variables, preferably at initialization, it is much safer, and much easier to debug when you have thousands of lines of code and what is happening is making absolutely no sense, as can often be the case with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot the "cin >> cstats;"

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int cstats, choice;
    int rhp, hp, i, init, atk, def, matk, mdef, dmg, mdmg, agi, magi;
    cout << "Please choose your specialty: ";
    cout << "[1] Offense [2] Magic [3] Defense [4] Speed";

    cin >> cstats;
    switch(cstats)
    {
        case 1:
            atk = 15;
            def = 5;
            agi = 5;
            break;
        case 2:
                   //other code
            break;
        ....
        default:
          //Here you can prompt to select 1,2,3 or 4
    }
}
```